# How do I draw a 2 normal distribution in one frame?

Tags: r, statistics, normal-distribution

Here is the problem:

2 groups:

Group A: initial cholesterol levels were normally distributed with mean=244 mg/100 ml and standard deviation = 51 mg/100 ml.

Group B: initial cholesterol levels were normally distributed with mean= 219 mg/100 ml and standard deviation=41 mg/100 ml.

The question I need to answer is how do I produce two normal distributions (group A + Group B) in the same frame?

Do i use the command `dnorm()`?

Here is my attempt at the code:

```
curve(dnorm(x, mean=219, sd=41))
```

the height of the curve is 1/(sqrt(2*pi)*sd)

Comment: Use `dnorm` if you want to generate an "idealised" curve where each point is a density for the normal distribution. Use `rnorm` if you want to generate simulated measurements which approximate the distribution. For the second case you'd want something like `plot(density(rnorm(400, 219, 41)))` (or a `ggplot2` solution).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can use `curve()`+`dnorm()`:

```
curve(dnorm(x, mean=219, sd=41), from = 0, to = 400)
curve(dnorm(x, mean=244, sd=51), add = TRUE, col = 2)
```

[image]